# ASP.NET How to determine if authenticated user can access a page or directory?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to check if an authenticated user is authorized to access a directory.

I have done this before with a base class library method, I just cannot remember what class it's part of or what it's name was. I think the method was a static method and the class may have had the word Utility in it's name, but I just can't remember or find it on the net. BUT I KNOW I HAVE USED IT! The method definition was something like:

```
bool SomeTypeWithTheWordUtilityInTheNamePossibly.VerifyUserIsAuthorized(Principal user, string virtualPath)
```

I'm not using a roles provider in this application and I'm not planning to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOUND IT! Thanks to [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rmclaws/archive/2006/12/04/asp-net-authenticated-but-not-authorized.aspx).

[UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.urlauthorizationmodule.checkurlaccessforprincipal%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)